# Отображение карты для мобильного устройства

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, как можно задать в АПИ яндекс карт, чтобы карта всегда отображалась как для мобильных устройств? Проблема в том, что при вызове карты из телеграма, во встроенном браузере телеграма контроллы карты очень плохо видно, пример на картинке.

[image: Подгрузка карты из телеграма]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить тэг meta с нужными вам параметрами https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Все отлично получилось, спасибо. Добавил <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> в html файл.